# Wordpress Media Library not working properly

Tags: wordpress, media, thumbnails, uploading

I'm having an issue with Wordpress media library. No matter how small or big the file, it takes a lot of time to upload, and in most cases it fails to upload; it justs freezes at like 10%. Also, when I try to upload a file, the whole website becomes slow and stops working until I close all the tabs and open the website again. There are like 80 images in the library but only about 10 are showing thumbnails.
Things I have tried but didn't work:
deactivating all the plugins,
deactivating the theme (set it to twenty twenty),
checking folder permission (755)
any help please?

Comment: Please advise what research you have done , what you have tried.   There are many similar sounding posts on stack and on the web. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks @anmari I have googled the solutions that I mentioned in the post, but none of them worked.

Comment: Does site meet https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/?